# What is object index of QTextFormat?

Tags: c++, qt

The function **int QTextFormat::objectIndex () const** returnes an object index. What is it? And what if I do the following:

```
    QTextBlockFormat bfmt;
    bfmt.setObjectIndex(0);
```

What this code does?

ADDED:
[Here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/demos-textedit-textedit-cpp.html) there is a function **void TextEdit::textStyle(int styleIndex)**. This function is for adding a list into QTextEdit, or making it a normal (standard text). In the function mentioned above there is a code snippet like this:

```
 } else {
     // ####
     QTextBlockFormat bfmt;
     bfmt.setObjectIndex(-1);
     cursor.mergeBlockFormat(bfmt);
 }
```

This code snippet is in order to make list a standard text. But it does not work and only works when I write

```
    QTextBlockFormat bfmt;
    bfmt.setObjectIndex(0);
    m_textCursor.mergeBlockFormat(bfmt);
    m_textEdit->setTextCursor(m_textCursor);
```

Please explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTextOjbects` are used to group parts of a `QTextDocument`. Some text objects would be `QTextList`, `QTextFrame`, `QTextTable` etc. Each of these text objects have an index. The `ojbectIndex` of a `QTextFormat` associates the format object with a text object.

Your code above would associate `bfmt` with the text object with index 0.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but please explain me what I had written in the ADDED block above. I hopped that the answer of my question will help me understand the Qt demo code but I need more help, please.